# Multiple JavaScript functions not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function calc(){
    var a = prompt("Enter a number");
    var b = prompt("Enter another number");
    var x = +a;
    var y = +b;
    alert("The answer is " + (x+y));
}
function rect(type){
    var a = prompt("Enter length of rectangle");
    var b = prompt("Enter width of rectangle");
    var x = +a;
    var b = +b;
    if(type=="area"){
        alert("The area is " + (x*y);
    }
    else if(type=="perimeter"){
        alert("The perimeter is " + ( (2*x)+(2*y) );
    }
}
</script>

<head>
    <title>JavaScript Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="calc()">Calculator</button>
    <button onclick="rect('area')">Area of Rectangle</button>
    <button onclick="rect('perimeter')">Perimeter of Rectangle</button>
</body>
```

When I comment out the rect function, my code runs fine, it's just that the Calculator button is the only one that works. The other two buttons should be working fine with the rect function, but they aren't, and when I un-comment the rect function the Calculator button stops working as well. Why is this?

Comment: Make sure you check your error console before asking questions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing some parentheses

```
alert("The area is " + (x*y));
// and:
alert("The perimeter is " + ( (2*x)+(2*y) ));
```

Comment: Nah, it's those little mistakes that are ones you look over.